# How to unit test ResultSetExtractor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need advice on how to unit test a ResultSetExtractor when using jdbc.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM item where item_id = ?";
    return (Item) jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Item>() {
      @Override
      public Item extractData(final ResultSet rs) throws ... {
        if (rs.next()) {
          Item item = new Item (rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
          return item ;
        } else
          return null;
      }
    }, itemId);
  }
```

With the above approach of using an anonymous class, I would have to use argumentCaptor to get the ResultSetExtractor. The test I have so far is below. I don't know how what to do next in terms of the ResultSetExtractor.

```
 @Test
  public void testGetItemByID() {
    ArgumentCaptor<ResultSetExtractor> rseCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ResultSetExtractor.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> stringCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM item where item_id = ?";
    itemDAOImpl.getItemByID(testId);
    verify(mockJdbcTemplate, times(1)).query(stringCaptor.capture(), rseCaptor.capture(), stringCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals(stringCaptor.getAllValues().get(0),sql);
    assertEquals(stringCaptor.getAllValues().get(1),testId);
  }
```

I dont know if using an anonymous class would make it harder to unit test. I could always pull the anonymous class out of the jdbc call and make a class like below, but I dont know where to start testing this class.

```
public class ItemResultSet implements ResultSetExtractor<Item> {
    @Override
    public Item extractData(ResultSet rs) throws ...{
      if (rs.next()) {
        Item item = new Item (rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
        return item ;
      } else
        return null;
    }
  }
```

The test below would pass with either implementations but I want to avoid using any(ResultSetExtractor.class). What I want is to test the actual implementation of extractData(final ResultSet rs) if possible.

```
@Test
  public void testGetItemByID() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM item where item_id = ?";
    when(mockJdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), any(ResultSetExtractor.class), anyString()))
        .thenReturn(testItem);
    assertEquals(testItem, itemDAOImpl.getItemByID(testId));
  }
```

Comment: You could call `resultSetExtractor.extractData (mockedResultSet)` directly from unit-test without using `jdbcTemplate`. And you may need two different tests: one when you have element in database and another when no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following

```
private ResultSet getMockResultSet() throws Exception {
    ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    Mockito.when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturn("Value 1");
    Mockito.when(rs.getString(2)).thenReturn("Value 2");
    return rs;
}

private ResultSet getEmptyMockResultSet() throws Exception {
    ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    Mockito.when(rs.next()).thenReturn(false);
    return rs;
}

@Test
public void testDataExists() {
    Item item = new ResultSetExtractor<Item>() {
        @Override
        public Item extractData(final ResultSet rs) throws ... {
            if (rs.next()) {
                Item item = new Item (rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
                return item ;
            } else
                return null;
        }
    }.extractDatae(getMockResultSet());
    assertEquals(item.getFirst(), "Value 1");
    assertEquals(item.getSecond(), "Value 2");
}


@Test
public void testNoDataExists() {
    Item item = new ResultSetExtractor<Item>() {
        @Override
        public Item extractData(final ResultSet rs) throws ... {
            if (rs.next()) {
                Item item = new Item (rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
                return item ;
            } else
                return null;
        }
    }.extractData(getEmptyMockResultSet());
    assertNull(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Awesome answer, definitely helps me.

Comment: So you just copy the implementation of `extractData` into the test? It seems fishy because the code that is getting run is a *copy* of the implementation, not the implementation itself. That could cause issues if the test and implementation get out of sync. The implementation could be wrong but the test still passes because the test has old code. Also, how would you get a code coverage analyzer to recognize this? Here is a better solution: http://www.kswaughs.com/2020/06/spring-jdbctemplate-resultsetextractor.html